# css resize: How to resize a dynamic growing div after max height is active

Tags: resize, css

I want to dynamically add items to the list. the list's height should be as high as the items are. but at a certain point, it's 300px, the ul should stop "growing" … i did this with "max-height". so far so good. NOW that i have a scrollbar I want to add a resize functionality, so that the user can decide if it's bigger than max-height or not.

The problem is that it can't resize higher than max-height. Does anybody know how to do this? the best way?

html:

```
<a href="#">click to add</a>

<ul>
    <li>start</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 300px;
    resize: vertical;
}
```

js/jquery:

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul').append('<li>item</li>');
});
```

here is the same on fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ZwrzX/
thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. i tried again on my own and came to the following:

```
var max_h = $('ul').css('max-height').replace('px', '');

function check_height() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('li').each(function () {
        sum += $(this).height();
    });
    if (sum >= max_h) $('ul').css({ 'height': max_h, 'max-height': sum });
    else $('ul').css({ 'height': 'auto', 'max-height': max_h });
}

$('#addItem').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul').append('<li>item</li>');

    check_height();
});

$('#removeItem').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li').last().remove();

    check_height();
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZwrzX/6/

I was asking if there is a cleaner solution. or a solution with less js?
any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZwrzX/4/

When the `UL` height reaches `290px`, a link appears besides the add item link and the user can click on it to add `25px` to the `max-height` of the `UL`, if the user clicks it 2 times, `50px` (2 x `25px`) is added to the `max-height` of the `UL`.

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="addItem">click to add item</a>
<a href="#" id="addHeight">Add 25px to UL Max height</a>
<ul>
    <li>start</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#addItem').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul').append('<li>item</li>');
    if ($('ul').height() > 290) {
        $('#addHeight').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
});

$('#addHeight').on('click', function() {
    var currenULtHeight = $('ul').height();
    $('ul').css('max-height', currenULtHeight + 25 + 'px')
});
```

CSS

```
ul {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 300px;
    resize: vertical;
}
#addHeight {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: that's not very beautiful. why should the user click the button and why 25px? what if the height's differ..

Comment: 1- "why should the user click the button", you said in your question "the user can decide if it's bigger than max-height or not" 2- "why 25px" : It's an example number to give you clue, you can use a different number based on your actual code.

Comment: ok. sorry. but what do you think of my own solution i've posted here?
actually i try to find a solution with less js .. do you think that's possible?

Comment: My solution adds to the height of the ul when there are more items, your solutions removes the extra items if it exceeds the height of the ul. So these are two different approaches. Your solution works as well if it satisfies your needs. You are already using jQuery, and there's not a css only solution, so you'll need more js anyways.